# Overlap Activity over another Actvity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an audio app where the user can select an item in a list that brings the user to a separate `Activity` which contains the controls to play/pause/skip forward/skip back/etc.

Is it possible to have the second `Activity` "peek" at the bottom of the first `Activity` then the user can slide the second `Activity` up to view the play controls?

I'm starting the second `Activity` with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EpisodeActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("episodeid", 0);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: CommonsWare has provided an answer, but if that isn't what you are looking for can you please draw a picture of what you mean, as it is difficult to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: I think a Bottom Sheet is what I'm looking for. It's for an audio app and when a user selects an audio item to play, I'd like the layout with the music controls to slide up and over the Activity with the list of audio items, instead of sending a user to a completely separate Activity.

Comment: Don't know if bottom sheet is what you want, but you can definitely use a `Fragment` or even just show/hide a set of `View`s in the current `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have the second Activity "peek" at the bottom of the first Activity then the user can slide the second Activity up to view the play controls?

No. You cannot have two activities both receiving user input. If the second activity can receive user input, then the user cannot also be able to interact with the first activity.

Your proposed UI sounds like a [bottom sheet](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom). You can implement a bottom sheet using fragments. Fragments themselves have been part of the Android SDK for a bit over a decade. A typical implementation of a bottom sheet would be based on [`BottomSheetDialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment).

Comment: Yeah, I think bottom sheet is what I'm looking for. thanks